# Keep an image open even with another fullscreen application

Tags: vb.net, image, fullscreen, basic

I am creating an application in Visual Basic, which simply opens an image overlaying the screen.

So far so good, only when I open something in fullscreen the image no longer appears. I need this image to stay open and displayed even if I open some other program on my SO in fullscreen, does anyone know anything?

This is running in my PC, Windows 10.

```
BackgroundImageLayout = None
StartPosition = CenterScreen
FormBorderStyle = None
```

Image 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpaQb.jpg

Image 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWUy9.jpg

I need the rule that appears in image 1 to keep appearing in image 2

Comment: You should get rid of that `End` statement.  That's not the way to exit a VB.NET app.    If it's the startup form then you can just call `Close`, or you can call `Application.Exit` anywhere.

Comment: Also, what has any of that code got to do with displaying an image?

Comment: Maybe this can help, [old post regarding heads up display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562863/overlay-text-on-some-elses-window-hud), there is some advice, but at least you can search on these terms:  heads up display or HUD, or overlay.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You're right. I changed the text, can you take a look?